# Editing specific element in Wordpress menu with nav_menu_item_id

Tags: php, wordpress, menu-items

I want to add number of items in wishlist next to li element in my "menu_main". To problem is I can't how to edit that specific element. I tried sth like

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'filter_function_name_5519', 10, 3 );
function filter_function_name_5519( $menu_id, $item, $args ){
    // filter...
    if (!is_admin() && $args->theme_location == 'menu_main' && 
yith_wcwl_count_products() && $menu_id == 'menu-item-5519') {
        $item .= '<li>' . yith_wcwl_count_products() . '</li>';
    }
    return $item;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Important for me is to echo `yith_wcwl_count_products()` within li element, because I need to position it with css via position relative and absolute.

Comment: do you create the `<li>` or is there nothing?

Comment: There already exists <li id="menu-item-5519" class="...">(anchor and text)</li>

Comment: and are you sure, that you should check `$menu_id` for your item id then?

Comment: Yes, because when I changed `$item .=` and `return $item` with `$menu_id .=` and `return $menu_id` I got `<li id="menu-item-5519<li>1</li>">....` so I want to get to the inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change  this way you are dealing with an object here so if you want to change the title you can do it this way:

```
 add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'filter_function_name_5519', 10, 3);
function filter_function_name_5519($menu_id, $item, $args)
{
    if (!is_admin() && $menu_id == 'menu-item-42') {
        $item->title .= ' test ';

    }


}
```

Comment: I do not want to change title or URL. I need to add content

Comment: just modified my answer so you can append whatever you want in the content